# Twilio 21211 error "not valid number" but it is

Tags: javascript, twilio, whatsapp, twilio-api

I am doing the whatsapp [tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/blog/send-whatsapp-messages-from-google-sheets-javascript-node-js) on twilio page. But when I try to run it gives me this error.
The number is ok, the twilio sandbox goes through with the exact same number.
Any ideas?

```
RestException [Error]: The 'To' number +5492xxxxxxxx is not a valid phone number.
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you are doing the WhatsApp tutorial, then you can't send from the WhatsApp sandbox to a regular phone number, you should prefix it with `whatsapp:`.

Alternatively, I am guessing that your account is a free trial account. Before you upgrade your account you are only able to send SMS messages to numbers that you verify with your account. To solve this, you should [verify the number](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/tutorials/how-to-use-your-free-trial-account#verify-your-personal-phone-number), or [upgrade your account](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223183208-Upgrading-to-a-paid-Twilio-Account).

Comment: thanks! Sorry for the late feedback